# I would like to create a field that reflects the sequence each record was created in?

Tags: qgis

I would like to create a field that reflects the sequence each record was created in?

I created a point feature that I added records in the specific sequence that I want them to be numbered in. But My attribute table does not give me the sequence I created each record in the ID on all the records is Null.

I don't know Python script well so I'll require detailed explanation please?

Answer (score 2):

No need for python. Create a new field with [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and the expression [`$id`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-record-and-attributes-id). It stores the order in which features were added.